# What do you mean by "by content"?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I'm not sure what the sentence below means.

> "All the materials we use are Australian by content and sourced globally."

what do you mean by "by content" here?
Is it like, they use Australian materials only when its content is good, and when it is not, they use those sourced globally?

or they use both of them but mainly Australian?

or anything else?

Comment: Perhaps, their legal status after they've been imported to Australia? The word 'content' has sometimes the meaning of 'proportion', 'share' in something. So, if one looked at the larger context of that sentence, perhaps, you could infer from it the meaning?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is supposed to mean; it appears to contradict itself. Surely if *all* of the materials are Australian then *none* of the materials are "sourced globally". What is the product?

Comment: Without additional information, I think you have to ask the company making the statement what it means. There could be a legitimate explanation, or it could be marketing mumbo-jumbo (purposely misleading).

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments! This sentence is from a homepage of an apparel maker, explaining what materials they use. So it is for consumers who may be interested in buying the products that the maker provides. After this sentence it goes something like their materials are safe and environmentally friendly etc.

Comment: I agree that the sentence doesn't seem to make sense at first. Perhaps they mean that the *types* of materials are Australian, even if they come from elsewhere?  Something like, "the materials are wool that's woven in the traditional Australian pattern, but the wool is from Mongolia and the weaving took place in Japan"?

Answer (score 2):

Fibre processing and garment production in Australia is not exactly booming...

I own a farm in South Australia, nearly all of our fleece (alpaca) goes overseas (New Zealand, South America and China mostly, occasionally Europe), there it's processed into fabric or garments and a lot of it is returned here for sale.

Hence - Australian by content, produced globally.

I'm assuming that's what you are seeing.

Comment: That makes sense. So a less confusing description might be "All raw materials are Australian, but some processing occurs overseas." (Except that that probably doesn't sound as good to the folks in the marketing department.)

Comment: @nnnnnn A subject close to my heart :) The law says that you can call it whatever you like as long as it's not misleading. If the manufacturer actually uses the Aus logo then rules are http://www.australianmade.com.au/for-business/using-the-logo/ much stricter But yes, your description would be correct for my example